# Alonzo being a hard fork, will Daedalus support it automatically?

Tags: daedalus

How should the users prepare for the upcoming Alonzo hard fork?

Will it be as simple as just updating the Daedalus wallet when it's out, or are there some precautious actions that we have to take *(Like undelagating from the pools etc)* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users of Cardano will have nothing they need to do.

Cardano uses the Hard Fork Combinator which allows upgrades to the protocol while keeping all previous blocks from the previous eras.

https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/explore-cardano/what-is-a-hard-fork-combinator.html#what-is-a-hard-fork-combinator

This process has taken place last year with Shelly that turned on the delegating system today.

Comment: Thank you so much.
It is relieving to know.